# Passing state in form of props through React Router Dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to pass the state as a prop with the help of react-router-dom, but it does give the error: No routes matched location "/quiz".

Here is the App.js file:

```js
import React from "react";
import Start from "./Start";
import Quiz from "./Quiz";
import "./App.css";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="" element={<Start />} />
        <Route exact path="/start" element={<Start />} />
        <Route exact path="/quiz/:type" element={<Quiz />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is the start.js file:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import "./start.css";

function Start() {
  const history = useNavigate();
  const [value, setValue] = useState({
    fname: "",
    lname: "",
  });
  const [store, setStore] = useState("");

  function AddData(event) {
    setStore(value);

    event.preventDefault();
    history("/quiz");
  }
  function handle(event) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setValue((prevValue) => {
      return { ...prevValue, [name]: value };
    });
  }

  return (
    <div className="start">
      <div className="start-body">
        <form onSubmit={AddData}>
          <h2>Enter Details</h2>
          <input onChange={handle} type="text" placeholder="Enter firstName" name="fname" />
          <input onChange={handle} type="text" placeholder="Enter lastName" name="lname" />
          <button>Submit</button>
          <Link
            to={{
              pathname: "/quiz/parameter-data",
              state: { local: store },
            }}
          ></Link>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Start;
```

Here when I click the button, it routes to the quiz component with the state as a prop, but it will show nothing and give the error in the console: No routes matched location "/quiz".

Here is the quiz file:

```
import React from 'react'
import {useParams,useLocation} from 'react-router-dom';
import "./quiz.css";
function Quiz() {
    const{type}=useParams();
    const value =useLocation().state.local;
  return (
    <div className="quiz">
        name:{value};  
    </div>
  )
}

export default Quiz
```

Here is the index.js file where I use  browserRouter:

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDom from "react-dom"
import App from "./App"
import {BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom"

    ReactDom.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
    
    ,document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: You would need to do `history.push('quiz/parameter-data', {{local:store}})` in `AddData()` function

Comment: I tried, but now it is giving syntax error about the curly braces around local: store

Comment: My bad use only one curly brace `history.push('quiz/parameter-data', {local:store})`

Answer (score 0):

First I would advise you to call the value returned by `useNavigate` `navigate` and not `history`, as `history` is the naming used in previous versions of React Router Dom:

```js
const navigate = useNavigate();
```

Second, you are navigating to `"/quiz"`, which doesn't exist in your Routes setup. There is only `"/quiz/something"`. Change `AddData` as below:

```js
function AddData(event) {
  setStore(value);
  event.preventDefault();
  navigate(`/quiz/${"value-to-get-with-useParams()-goes-here"}`, {
    state: { local: "value-to-get-with-useLocation()-goes-here" },
  });
}
```

Here you would get the two passed data to `Quiz` as you defined it:

```
<Route exact path="/quiz/:type" element={<Quiz />} />
```

```js
export default function Quiz() {
  const { type } = useParams();
  const { state } = useLocation();
  return <div></div>;
```

Comment: I tried the same but  it  still shows the same error

Comment: It's saying  No routes matched location "/quiz" ?

Comment: yes it is saying No routes matched location "/quiz"

Comment: That's weird. I edited the navigate part of my answer. Give it a try again.

Comment: And can you tell your React Router Dom version?

Comment: React-router-Dom version is  6.3.0

Comment: i tried but it still shows same error

Comment: See this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-v6-forked-7nciqv?file=/src/App.js). It should work.

Comment: now it is giving error,cannot read the properties of null(reading local)

Comment: This line `const value =useLocation().state.local;`  is causing the issue. What are trying to get with this.

Comment: i want to get the value of store (which is a state) having  the value of (value state) which getting input value from onChange event as I type

Comment: like as I type hello world in start components through inputs,  I want to get this hello world value in quiz component as I route

Comment: If you wanna pass data with `useLocation`, you should change a little bit the `navigate`. Take my updated answer.

Comment: i want state to be dynamic not the hardcoded value

Comment: You just change what's hardcoded with what's dynamic that you want, no?

Comment: i change it with the dynamic value but it does not work

Comment: Can you past here what you have changed?

Comment: function AddData(event){
     
     setStore(value);
  
    
    event.preventDefault();
     navigate(`/quiz/${"whatever value you pass"} `,{state:{local:{store}},
   } );
    
    }

Comment: It should be `local:store` not `local:{store}`. Use the below one:

Comment: function AddData(event){ setStore(value); event.preventDefault(); navigate(/quiz/${"whatever value you pass"} ,{state:{local:store}, } ); }

Comment: i tried this but still not work

Comment: Are you getting any error in the console?

Comment: no ,but it does not pass any props which I write

Comment: Can you fork this [CodeSanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-v6-forked-7nciqv?file=/src/App.js) and recreate your project so I could help.

Comment: i forked it you can see it in https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-v6-forked-2dx72g

Comment: You just added empty files, and the rest is what I created. I cannot reproduce your problem with that. With what I gave you, it should work normally. Make sure you are spelling everything correctly. And if you have a new error, past it on Google, you would certainly find an answer on Stack Overflow.